# Azure Notification Hub - NotificationHubClient.SendAppleNativeNotificationAsync Hanging

Tags: c#, .net, apple-push-notifications, azure-notificationhub, azure-hub

I have the following code:

```
 var alert = "{\"aps\":{\"alert\":\"" + message + "\"}}";
 outcome = await ApnsNotifications.Instance.Hub.SendAppleNativeNotificationAsync(alert, username);
```

Bu the await just hangs forever and never returns.  Should I just "fire and forget" this by not awaiting, or is there some other way to make sure this doesn't hang?

I should note that the `username` may or may not have an iphone - so hopefully there's no requirement to actually have a device to send to with these.

Comment: I saw your [other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40363918/async-task-hanging) about it. Could you share more details about your environment? Do you know whether an HTTP request even leaves the machine? Also, if you try running it locally, do you get the same behavior?

Comment: @NikitaG.I am going to try to apply the recommendations from that question to see if it resolves the issue... I'll let you know :)