# Async task hanging

Tags: c#, .net, async-await, apple-push-notifications, azure-notificationhub

I have the following code:

```
public async Task SendPushNotificationAsync(string username, string message)
{
    var task = ApnsNotifications.Instance.Hub.SendAppleNativeNotificationAsync(alert, username);
    if (await Task.WhenAny(task, Task.Delay(500)) == task) {
       return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

I noticed that `SendAppleNativeNotificationAsync` was hanging indefinitely (never returning out of the containing method), so I tried telling it to cancel after 500ms.  But still... the call to `WhenAny` now hangs and I never see a `return` get hit, resulting in the consumer just waiting indefinitely (it's a sync method calling this async method, so I call .Wait()):

```
_commService.SendPushNotificationAsync(user.Username, notificationDto.PushContent).Wait(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
```

How do I force this to finish after a set time, no matter what?

What happens if I simply "fire and forget", instead of `await`ing the Task?

Comment: Where do you execute this code? I mean, web application, desktop application, maybe mobile?

Comment: @Evk this is in a service method called from a sync service method, called by a WebApi controller.

Comment: Don't ever use Wait (or Task.Result) together with async\await in environments with "UI" or "request" thread - it will deadlock just like you observe.

Comment: @Evk is this "Deadlock" or just "blocking until something finishes"?

Comment: This is deadlock, but the reasons I cannot explain in comments, you can see them in duplicate question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> it's a sync method calling this async method, so I call .Wait()

And that's your problem. You're [deadlocking because you're blocking on asynchronous code](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html).

The best solution for this is to use `await` instead of `Wait`:

```
await _commService.SendPushNotificationAsync(user.Username, notificationDto.PushContent);
```

If you **absolutely can't** use `await`, then you can try one of the hacks described in my [Brownfield Async article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/mt238404.aspx).

Comment: Thanks for this.  If I use `await` and `SendAppleNativeNotificationAsync` never returns, will I be ok?

Comment: @SB2055: Why would it never return?

Comment: I'm basing that on the behavior I'm seeing from my debugger - I can never catch a `return` but maybe that's because another thread is picking it up?

Comment: @SB2055: Blocking on it will *prevent* completion. If you `await` it, it should work fine.

Comment: @StephenCleary I'm having this exactl problem in an async method. When setting a breakpoint an an await, the next line of code is never invoked with the task hanging, despite the message being delivered to the endpoint.

Comment: I'm also having this exactl problem in an async method. When setting a breakpoint an an await, the next line of code is never invoked with the task hanging, despite the message being delivered to the endpoint